# FOSUserBundle edit user not working properly

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle, the problem I have encountered was in editing a user account, when I tried to edit a specific user account, the retrieved user info is correct but when I tried to update the retrieved user info, the currently logged account would be the one being edited not the retrieved user account, how is it possible? What's wrong with my code?

ProfileController :
//edit user

```
public function editUserAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('MatrixUserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!is_object($user)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm(); 
        $form->setData($user); 
        $form->handleRequest($request); 

        if ($form->isValid()) { 
            /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */

            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
            $userManager->updateUser($user); 

            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('message', 'Successfully updated'); 
            $url = $this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_viewUser'); 
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url); 
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Comment: What data are you updating? I mean data like roles doesn't update immediately you have to logout and login again

Comment: That code looks fine, maybe you are looking in the wrong place. What are you doing that leads you to believe the logged in user is being edited?

Comment: Check that you have set `use_listener` to false - the built in listener may be kicking in and saving changes for you. http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html#updating-a-user-object

Answer (score 0):

After the given user is correctly updated, you are returning a redirection to a custom route.

I guess the route `matrix_edi_viewUser` is an override of the original `FOSUB\ProfileController::showAction`.

Also, you have to create a specific showUserAction and pass it the updated user as argument.
The following code should works :

```
public function showUserAction($id)
{
    $user = $em->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('MatrixUserBundle:User')
        ->find($id);

    if (!is_object($user)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:show.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
}
```

The route :

```
matrix_edi_viewUser:
    path:     /users/{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: MatrixUserBundle:Profile:showUser }
```

And in your editAction, change your redirection to :

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('matrix_edi_viewUser', array('id' => $user->getId()); 
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Now, the user informations displayed in show will be the informations of the updated user.

Comment: thanks, but what I want is to display all the users, and then just add an edit action wherein when I click that specific user, it must be the one to be updated.

Comment: This is what I do. Actually, you are using the current authenticated user to display the informations (your route viewUser doesnt take any user as parameter), change it by retrieving the updated user, not using the security token user.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it since I am just new in using FOSuserbundle?

Comment: Is your problem : when you update an user, the user updated is the current loggedin ?